# Find the iverse of the followning bounded operator?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, semigroup-of-operators

The following definition and Theorem are given in the book **"A short course on operator semigroup" by the author "K-J Engel and R Nagel"**.

**Sectoral operator:** A closed linear operator $(A,D(A))$ in Banach space $X$ is called sectoral (of angle $\delta$) if there exists $0<\delta\leq\frac{\pi}{2}$ such that sector $\sum_{\frac{\pi}{2}+\delta}:=\{\lambda\in \mathbb{C}:| arg\lambda |<\frac{\pi}{2}+\delta\} \backslash\{0\}$ is contained in the resolvent set $\rho(A),$ and if for each $\epsilon\in (0,\delta)$, there exists $M_{\epsilon}\geq1$ such that$$\|R(\lambda,A)\|\leq\frac{M_{\epsilon}}{|\lambda|},$$  for $0\neq\lambda\in \overline{\sum_{\frac{\pi}{2}+\delta-\epsilon}}. $  Again, we know the following theorem

**Theorem** An operator $(A,D(A))$ on a Banach space $X$ generates a bounded analytic semigroup $\Big\{T(z):z\in\sum_{\delta}\cup\{0\}\Big\}$ on $X$ if and only if A is densly defined and sectoral operator.

Where $T(0)=I$ and for $z\in\sum_{\delta}$, $$T(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma}e^{\mu z}R(\mu,A)d\mu$$ where $\gamma$ is any piecewise smooth curve in  $\sum_{\frac{\pi}{2}+\delta}$ going from $\infty e^{-i(\frac{\pi}{2}+\delta')}$ to $\infty e^{i(\frac{\pi}{2}+\delta')}$, for some $\delta'\in(|argz|,\delta)$.

In the chapter 5 of the book **"R. deLaubenfels, Existence Families, Functional calculi and Evollution Equations, springer-verlag, Berlin,1994"** at page no 69, it is given that $T(z)$ are one to one and it's range is dense in $X$.

**My question: For $t>0$, What is the inverse operator of $T(t)$ from it's range set in term of contour integration?** Please help me.

I was expecting  $$T(-t)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma}e^{-\mu t}R(\mu,A)d\mu$$ would be the inverse of T(t) but what i found , it can not be. please help me.

Comment: The heat equation is not reversible in time. That corresponds to the classical analytic semigroup where, at any positive time, $T(t)f$ is in the domain of every positive power of the generator. The Poisson semigroup has the same property.

Comment: @TrialAndError :  You want to say that inverse can not define in term of contour integration? The property you mention that is the property of analytic semigroup for positive time.

Comment: @TrialAndError:  I want Inverse of the linear operator $T(t)$, may not bounded. I am looking for form of inverse of $T(t)$.

Comment: How do you know that the form you have is not correct? It's tough to recognize the domain of the inverse, isn't it? How many functions are you going to find that are in the domain of the inverse for all $t$? Can you find even one?

Comment: @TrialAndError: The domain of the inverse is the range of the operator T(t). I was started doing by taking one element from the range but I got some problem.

Comment: Have you tried combining the forward and backward integrals where the backward time would be smaller than the forward?

Comment: @TrialAndError: I have tried as the proof of  $T(z_1+z_2)=T(z_1)T(z_2)$ in the book  A short course on operator semigroup" by the author "K-J Engel and R Nagel for $x\in X$.I  got the problem due to appearance of $e^{-t\mu}$. I can explain you the way i was trying to do.

Comment: I would start with $T(t_{max})=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma}e^{\mu t_{max}}R(\mu,A)d\mu$, apply $e^{-\mu' t}R(\mu',A)$ for $0 < t < t_{max}$, perhaps apply the resolvent equation, and see if I could now integrate over some contour in $\mu'$. The presence of $t_{max}$ may be enough to be able to perform the integral you want.

Comment: @TrialAndError: In time of doing integration I have faced same problem due to presence of $e^{-\mu' t}$.  you are choosing any $t\in (0,t_{max})$   to get inverse of $T(t_{max})$ . That means inverse may not unique if the value of the expecting integral is different  for different $t$. But if inverse exist it is unique.

Comment: It's a good place to start because you only expect to find a formula for the inverse $T(t)^{-1}$ when applied to the range of $T(s)$ for some $s \ge t$. However, it may be a little delicate to use $t=s$, but less so if you look at $T(t)^{-1}T(s)$ for $t < s$. Then, when combining the integrals, you may expect the exponential behaviors to work out okay. At least that's what I would try.

Comment: @TrialAndError: Thank you for your comment but i don't have idea to get the exponential behaviors what you said.